# JSF components are not rendered when running Spring Boot app on Eclipse Tomcat

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-boot, jsf-2.2

I have Spring Boot JSF application that runs fine on embedded Tomcat
but when trying to run it on Eclipse Tomcat, the jsf components are not getting rendered, here's my pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion> 

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-accessing-data-jpa</artifactId>  
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <packaging>war</packaging>


    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>    

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!--  
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            -->
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>org.jboss.repository.releases</id>
            <name>JBoss Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

**The main class:**

```
package hello;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.faces.application.ProjectStage;
import javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.HandlesTypes;

import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatContextCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import com.sun.faces.config.FacesInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletContextInitializer servletContextCustomizer() {
        return new ServletContextInitializer() {
            @Override
            public void onStartup(ServletContext sc) throws ServletException {
                sc.setInitParameter(ProjectStage.PROJECT_STAGE_PARAM_NAME, ProjectStage.Development.name());
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public static CustomScopeConfigurer customScopeConfigurer() {
        CustomScopeConfigurer configurer = new CustomScopeConfigurer();
        configurer.setScopes(Collections.<String, Object>singletonMap(FacesViewScope.NAME, new FacesViewScope()));
        return configurer;
    }

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory embeddedServletContainerFactory() {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();

        tomcat.addContextCustomizers(new TomcatContextCustomizer() {
            @Override
            public void customize(Context context) {
                context.addServletContainerInitializer(new FacesInitializer(),
                        getServletContainerInitializerHandlesTypes(FacesInitializer.class));
                context.addWelcomeFile("index.xhtml");
                context.addMimeMapping("eot", "application/vnd.ms-fontobject");
                context.addMimeMapping("ttf", "application/x-font-ttf");
                context.addMimeMapping("woff", "application/x-font-woff");
            }
        });

        return tomcat;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private Set<Class<?>> getServletContainerInitializerHandlesTypes(
            Class<? extends ServletContainerInitializer> sciClass) {
        HandlesTypes annotation = sciClass.getAnnotation(HandlesTypes.class);
        if (annotation == null) {
            return Collections.emptySet();
        }

        Class[] classesArray = annotation.value();
        Set<Class<?>> classesSet = new HashSet<Class<?>>(classesArray.length);
        for (Class clazz : classesArray) {
            classesSet.add(clazz);
        }

        return classesSet;
    }

}
```

**Other configuration:**

- JSF are added to project facets
- Maven dependencies are added in deployment assembly

When running the application on server, I don't get any errors in fact I see logs meaning that JSF was started successfully:

```
2017-01-28 16:04:47.145  INFO 6880 --- [ost-startStop-1] hello.Application                        : Started Application in 13.522 seconds (JVM running for 19.312)
2017-01-28 16:04:47.231  INFO 6880 --- [ost-startStop-1] j.e.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config     : Initializing Mojarra 2.2.14 ( 20161114-2153 unable to get svn info) for context '/spring-hibernate-jsf-web'
2017-01-28 16:04:47.539  INFO 6880 --- [ost-startStop-1] j.e.r.webcontainer.jsf.application       : JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
2017-01-28 16:04:48.557  INFO 6880 --- [ost-startStop-1] j.e.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config     : Monitoring file:/C:/Users/lenovo/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/spring-hibernate-jsf-web/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
2017-01-28 16:04:48.630  INFO 6880 --- [ost-startStop-1] .w.PostConstructApplicationEventListener : Running on PrimeFaces 6.0
2017-01-28 16:04:48.790  INFO 6880 --- [           main] org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNioProtocol     : Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
2017-01-28 16:04:48.799  INFO 6880 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina     : Server startup in 20021 ms
2017-01-28 16:04:49.463  INFO 6880 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .a.c.c.C.[.[.[/spring-hibernate-jsf-web] : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-01-28 16:04:49.463  INFO 6880 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-01-28 16:04:49.511  INFO 6880 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 47 ms
```

When accessing the xhtml page, there are no errors but the jsf and Primefaces components doesn't get rendered. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, it's weird, while running the jar on embeded tomcat i was able to access the xhtml pages without the /faces/ prefix but on eclipse tomcat i have to add /faces/ prefix before the xhtml page in order to work properly.

Comment: Seems it's related with your faces servlet configuration, how do you configure it?

Comment: @Xtreme Biker, i don't do faces configuration, springboot does it automatically

Comment: You have to declare and configure the jsf servlet via Java configuration, as far as I know. Spring boot is valid to configure spring mvc.

Comment: @Xtreme Biker, springboot now makes the configuration based on the dependencies, in the above code i didn't make any jsf configuration and it works fine !

Comment: Mmh, I don't think so, could you provide some link to the docs? I haven't read anything about it. Personally, I'm dealing with a production stage project which has boot + JSF + Primefaces and I had to: 1. Configure the faces servlet 2. Declare a custom Spring scope to emulate the JSF view scope 3. Configure the filter for Primefaces file upload components.  Also I haven't seen any [spring configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) to declare any JSF property. Still, good luck with it ;-)

Comment: @Xtreme Biker, please see the following link which i have based my project on, it doesn't have any JSF configuration for the faces servlet ! https://github.com/igormukhin/spring-boot-sample-jsf

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh - Spring Boot does not autoconfigure a FacesServlet for you. You are using FacesInitializer which creates the FacesServlet for you.